# equivalent of iptables rule in ip6tables

Tags: linux, bash, iptables, firewall, ip6tables

I have the following iptables rules in the source code of a project

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING ! -i br0 -p TCP --dport 45 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1000
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -i br0 -p TCP --dport 45 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 23
```

`br0` is the lan interface

Can any one explain to me the both rules.

And How to write the equivalent of these rules in ip6 with `ip6tables`